# Frameset / PHP loses session variable if clicking inside frame

Tags: php, session, frames

I am using frames for my site (I know not optimal, it is planned to be changed in the future)

Using the navigation on the left, the session variables are passed correctly.

However, if i click to open a new page from inside the frame "content" and to replace it, a new session is created.

I have session_start() at the beginning of each page as well tried using the header workaround, however nothing fixes the issue. If i look into the sessiondata folder, i see that upon changing the "content" frame, a new session is created.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))  {
session_start();·
}
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

-- frameset:

```
<?php session_start();
if($_SESSION['email']==''){echo 'please login with your credentials';}else if($_SESSION['email']!='') {
    session_save_path('/var/www/home/path/sessiondata/');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Website Name.</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
  <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://domain.com/favico.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>


<frameset rows="11%,89%" frameborder="1" framespacing="1" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" border="0" bordercolor="#ffffff">
  <frame name="bar" src="report/index1.php" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">

  <frameset id="mainset" cols="137,5,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="1" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" border="0" bordercolor="#ffffff">
    <frame name="menu" src="report/index_002.php" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize">
    <frame name="function" src="report/index_003.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" border="0" framespacing="0" noresize="noresize">
        <frame name="content" src="report/index_004.php" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize">
      </frameset>
  <noframes><body><p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p></body></noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using _session_save_path('/var/www/home/path/sessiondata/');_ ?

Comment: Hi bub, this was recommended as one of the sources for the session data to be lost, if the directory is not writeable. The path /var/www/home/path/sessiondata/ is accessible by www-data, is specified in php.ini as well lies within the webpage path and is not an external directory.

Comment: session_start() should not be conditionnal

Comment: FLX, I have tried to make the session_start() without the condition as well. Still, no change in the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 if($_SESSION['email']==''){
      echo 'please login with your credentials';
 } else if($_SESSION['email']!='') {
      session_save_path('/var/www/home/path/sessiondata/');
?>
```

Take some time to think about what this code is doing. session_start() means either

- use the supplied session token to retrieve the session data from the default location
- create a session id, then create a new session in the default location identified by the session id

While session_save_path() means any future reads or writes applied to the session data to go to this location rather than the default.

Hence your code will never retrieve an authenticated session (since session_save_path() is after session_start()). And, coincidentally, the behaviour you've described here cannot be created by the code you've shown us (implying different code elsewhere or at another time has been interacting with the session data).

Comment: My php.ini uses as well:session.save_path="/var/www/home/path/sessiondata", so this should be the default. If commenting out the session_save_path, the behaviour is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround to this issue is currently passing the session id as a parameter. It is strange that it works for all the other pages called from the left navigation.

```
echo "<TD align='center'> <a href='http://domain.com/path/report/showt.php?option=$data&id=$iid&sess=$sessid' target='content'> Detail of $data</a></TD>\n";
```

And in the respective file showt.php which gets called:

```
<?php
$sessid= $_REQUEST['sess'];
session_id($sessid);
session_start();·
print_r($_SESSION);
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
?>
```